# String concatenation, error

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

> Container.cc: In member function ‘std::string Container::tostring()’:
>   Container.cc:125:27: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’
>   and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’
>       cadena= "("+ this->id+ ","+this->weight +","+ this->price+")";

How I can solve this error, is c++

This is the code:

```
string Container::tostring()
    {
        cadena= "("+ this->id+ ","+this->weight +","+ this->price+")";

        return cadena;
    }
```

Comment: How are declared id, weight and price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write at least like

```
string Container::tostring()
    {
        cadena= "("+ std::to_string( this->id ) + "," + std::to_string( this->weight ) + "," +  std::to_string( this->price ) + ")";

        return cadena;
    }
```

Another way is the following

```
#include <sstream>

//...

string Container::tostring()
    {
        std::ostringstream os;

        os << "(" << this->id << "," << this->weight << "," << this->price << ")";
        cadena = os.str();

        return cadena;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't *start* with a `std::string` object.

Change to e.g

```
cadena = std::string("(") + this->id + ...
```

The above answer assumes that all variables involved are *strings* (`std::string` or `char` pointers or arrays). If that's not true you either have to convert the non-strings to strings (using e.g. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)) or by using a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and extracting the string from that stream.